# Scrapy store data in Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am currently learning Scrapy and I want to crawl the price and properties of Rolex watches. So far my crawler is running and displaying all the data correctly. However, now I want to save the data from my crawler to a mysql database, however I am having problems. I get the data with the crawler "Watchbot" however the pipeline does not get the items. I have already checked Settings.py and enabled the pipeline. Where exactly is my error and how can I transfer the data to the mysql DB?

This is my cralwer called Watchbot

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from watches.watches.items import WatchesItem


class WatchbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "watchbot"
    start_urls = ["https://www.watch.de/english/rolex.html"]


def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    for link in response.css("div.product-item-link a::attr(href)"):
        url = link.get()
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_categories)


def parse_categories(self, response):
    item = WatchesItem()
    item["itemnr"] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="sku"]/text()').extract()[0]
    item["reference"] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="mpn"]/text()').extract()[0]
    item["year"] = response.xpath(
        '//div[@class="product-option baujahr"]/div[@class="product-option-value"]/text()'
    ).extract()[0]
    yield item
```

That is the Pipeline.py

```
import mysql
from watches.watches.spiders import watchbot


class WatchesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="", user="", passwd="", database="")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute(
            """insert into watches values (%s), (%s), (%s)""",
            (item["YEAR"][0], item["REFERENCE"][0], item["ITEMNR"][0]),
        )
        self.conn.commit()
```

and that is my items.py

```
import scrapy


class WatchesItem(scrapy.Item):
    year = scrapy.Field()
    itemnr = scrapy.Field()
    reference = scrapy.Field()
    print(itemnr)
```

Comment: Well, for one that should be `insert into watches values (%s, %s, %s)` to insert those in a single row...

Comment: Thank you for formatting the code. Unfortunately it doesn't work with that line. Can you give me another hint?